# Работа с Timestamp

Tags: java

В базе хранится дата в формате TIMESTAMP. В базе записана вот эта дата

> 2010-12-04 01:45:06

Выбирается поле вот так. Естественно поле в java имеет тип тоже timestamp.

```
resultSet.getTimestamp("timestamp")
```

Затем в формате json клиенту возвращается вот это:

> 2010-12-04 01:45:06.0

а надо, чтоб вернулось вот в таком формате:

> 2010-12-03T17:45:06Z

Если использовать

```
timestamp.toLocalDateTime()
```

то возвращается вот это:

> 2010-12-04T01:45:06

Если использовать

```
timestamp.toInstant()
```

то возвращается:

> 2010-12-03T22:45:06Z

И в обоих случаях запись имеет неверное время. Что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Вы не совсем верно понимаете, похоже то что вы хотите получить. Если в конце стоит `Z` - это означает время в универсальном формате (то есть мировое время, приведенное к 0-му меридиану), поэтому у вас время и отличается.

А в БД у вас время в каком часовом поясе хранится?

> Z stands for Zulu time, which is also GMT and UTC.

По хорошему надо делать так.

```
//готовим формат вывода
private final static String ISO_8601_FORMAT_STRING="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(ISO_8601_FORMAT_STRING, Locale.ENGLISH);
TimeZone utcTimeZone=TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"); //задаем часовой пояс
dateFormat.setTimeZone(utcTimeZone);

//выводим
Timestamp myTimestamp; //таймстемп из БД
String s=dateFormat.format(myTimestamp); //собственно вывод
```